# Prove a result on transitive group actions.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ & $B$ be two sets s.t. $G$ acts transitively on each of $A$ & $B$.
Choose some $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $A$ & $B$ respectively then prove that if $G=G_\alpha G_\beta$ then $G=G_x G_y$ for all $x$ $\in A$ & $y$ $\in B$   where $G_x$ is stabilizer of $x$ in $G$ and similarly $G_\alpha$ be the stabilizer of $\alpha$ and $G_y$ is the stabilizer of $y$.

I know we have to choose some elements and apply some manipulative trick. it is hardly 2 liner but just can't think of right elements. help!

Comment: I'd guess you want to use conjugation, since conjugation is 'doing the same thing somewhere else', and you want to change things that fix $\alpha$ for things that fix $x$.

Comment: Follow your nose: apply the definition of transitivity using $\alpha,x \in A$ and using $\beta,y \in B$.

Comment: i tried. like let $g=g_\alpha$ $g_\beta$ where $g_\alpha$ $\in$ $G_\alpha$ and $g_\beta$ $\in$ $G_\beta$ and let $\tau$ be an element of $G$ which takes $\alpha$ to $x$ then if i write $g$= $g_\alpha \tau \tau^{-1} g_\beta$ then $g_\alpha \tau$ $\in$ $G_x$ but $\tau^{-1} g_\beta$ does not have to be in $G_y$ unless $\tau$ takes some $\theta$ to $y$ and $g_\beta$ takes $\theta$ to $y$. nothing concrete here.

Comment: Assum that $G$ is finite.

By transitivity, we need only to prove that $G=G_\alpha G_y$ for $y \in B$. Since $G$ is finite, we need only prove $|G_\alpha \cap G_\beta|=|G_\alpha \cap G_y|$.

Let $y=\beta^g$. Then $G_y=g^{-1}G_\beta g$. Since $G=G_\alpha G_\beta$, $g=g_1 g_2$, where $g_1 \in G_\beta$ and $g_2 \in G_\alpha$. Thus $G_y=g_2^{-1}G_\beta g_2$. We get $|G_\alpha \cap G_\beta|=|G_\alpha \cap G_y|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G = G_\alpha G_\beta$ is equivalent to $G_\alpha$ acting transitively on $B$, which implies that any conjugate of $G_\alpha$ in $G$ is transitive on $B$. But the conjugates of $G_\alpha$ are the stabilizers $G_x$, so we get $G = G_x G_\beta$ for all $x \in A$. Then, conjugating this equation by elements of $G$ gives $G = G_x G_y$ for all $x \in A$, $Y \in B$.

Comment: I am sorry but i am not getting why any conjugate of $G_\alpha$ in $G$ is transitive on $B$ if $G_\alpha$ acts transitively on $B$.
Let $g G_\alpha g^{-1}$ be any conjugate of $G_\alpha$ in $G$. Let $b$ be any element of  $B$ then how to get $\beta$ by applying $g G_\alpha g^-1$ on $b$?

To see this may be i should use that perm representation $\phi$ of $G_\alpha$ to $S_{|B|}$ must be onto as $G_\alpha$ acts transitively on $B$, then $\phi'$ be permutation representation of $g G_\alpha g^{-1}$ to $S_{|B|}$, then it will be onto too? Am i right?

Comment: Since we are assuming that $G_\alpha$ is transitive on $B$, there exists $x \in G_\alpha$ with $x(g^{-1}(b)) = g^{-1}(\beta)$.

Comment: to prove this $G = G_\alpha G_\beta$ is equivalent to $G_\alpha$ acting transitively on $B$, i got the only if direction but for if direction i.e. how to prove if $G_\alpha$ acting transitively on $B$ then $G = G_\alpha G_\beta$?